# apt-get install automatically cancelled

Tags: boot, apt, software-installation, aptitude

When I'm doing an update or installation on Ubuntu 13.10, the task is automatically cancelled in the terminal. I got this error since that the \boot partition was missing some space. I fixed this issue in removing older kernels, but installation still locked.

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-numpy python-scipy python-networkx
[sudo] password for steve: 
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances       
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
python-numpy est déjà la plus récente version disponible.
python-numpy passé en « installé manuellement ».
Les paquets supplémentaires suivants seront installés : 
  graphviz libcdt4 libcgraph5 libexpat1-dev libgraph4 libgvc5 libgvpr1 libpathplan4 libpython-dev libpython2.7-dev python-dateutil
  python-decorator python-dev python-matplotlib python-matplotlib-data python-pygraphviz python-pyparsing python-tz python-yaml
  python2.7-dev
Paquets suggérés :
  graphviz-doc ipython python-configobj python-excelerator python-fltk python-matplotlib-doc python-traits
Les NOUVEAUX paquets suivants seront installés :
  graphviz libcdt4 libcgraph5 libexpat1-dev libgraph4 libgvc5 libgvpr1 libpathplan4 libpython-dev libpython2.7-dev python-dateutil
  python-decorator python-dev python-matplotlib python-matplotlib-data python-networkx python-pygraphviz python-pyparsing
  python-scipy python-tz python-yaml python2.7-dev
0 mis à jour, 22 nouvellement installés, 0 à enlever et 1 non mis à jour.
Il est nécessaire de prendre 41.1 Mo dans les archives.
Après cette opération, 84.9 Mo d'espace disque supplémentaires seront utilisés.
Souhaitez-vous continuer [O/n] ? o
Annulation.
```

Comment: Do you have enough free space to complete the process? " 84.9 Mo d'espace disque supplémentaires seront utilisés."

Comment: Assuming you have enough space on disk, try running an update as in **sudo apt-get update**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The terminal input language has been changed to English. Following the command, the terminal is questioning the user in french but the answer need to be in English (`y` or`Y` instead of `o` or `O`).

**To fix this issue**:

1. Open a terminal
2. Type `locale` and make sure everything is setup in English (or your native language)

**If not**:

3. Type `sudo -i gedit /etc/default/locale` and change the following line:

   ```
   LANG="en_US" 
   LANGUAGE="en_US:en"
   ```
4. Also change these two lines in `sudo gedit ~/.pam_environment`:

   ```
   LANG=en_US 
   LANGUAGE=en_US
   ```
5. `sudo reboot`

And it's done.